# HTML message through EmailMessage in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email

This question should be very simple but basically I am looking for a way to send an html email using the Email message class in asp.net. on my debug site the mail client is a pop server so I just use an SmtpClient and add an AlternateView sending using the MailMessage class. The live site uses an Exchange server so I have to add Exchange credentials and send using the EMailMessage class but Email message doesn't define AlternateView. I am having a surprisingly hard time finding this answer on google. here are my two methods for taking the HTML Page and Sending the Email:

```
 private void emailUserPass(UserInfo info)
        {
            try
            {
                string body = string.Empty;
                using (StreamReader welcomeEmailReader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/path")))
                {
                    body = welcomeEmailReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                body = body.Replace("{ID}",info.ID.ToString());
                body = body.Replace("{Password}", info.Password);
                List<string> to = new List<string>(); to.Add(info.Email);

                SendEMail("New Login", body, to, new List<string>(), new List<string>());
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ShowError("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }



        public static void SendEMail(string subject, string body, List<string> to, List<string> cc, List<string> bcc)
        {
            #if DEBUG
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtpout.secureserver.net", 25);
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("login", "password");
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("email", "email");
                msg.Subject = subject;
                body = body.Replace("{To}","To " + string.Join(",", to));
                body = body.Replace("{CC}","CC " + string.Join(",", cc));
                body = body.Replace("{BCC}", "BCC " + string.Join(",", bcc));
                AlternateView plain = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/plain");
                AlternateView normal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");
                msg.AlternateViews.Add(plain);
                msg.AlternateViews.Add(normal);
                client.Send(msg);
#else
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
                ExchangeService exService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

                exService.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                exService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("No_reply_programs", "blah", "blah");
                exService.Url = new Uri("ExchangeURL");

                body = body.Replace("{To}",string.Empty);
                body = body.Replace("{CC}",string.Empty);
                body = body.Replace("{BCC}",string.Empty);

                EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(exService);
                AlternateView plain = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/plain");
                AlternateView normal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");
                msg.AlternateViews.Add(plain);
                msg.AlternateViews.Add(normal);
                msg.Subject = subject;
                foreach (string address in to)
                    msg.ToRecipients.Add(address);
                foreach (string address in cc)
                    msg.CcRecipients.Add(address);
                foreach (string address in bcc)
                    msg.BccRecipients.Add(address);
                msg.BccRecipients.Add("BccRecipient");
                msg.Send();
#endif
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use Exchange's SMTP server?

Comment: For one, they wanted to have it come from the same no_reply_programs as other plain text emails other classes in the module. Secondly, I have the Exchange credentials listed in the code but I do not have the SMTP password. I'd find it strange that EmailMessage would have no way to send html so I'm sure there is some way I just can't find it for the life of me

Comment: Also the EmailMessage.Body has a BodyType property according to intellisense but MSDN has not documentation on EmailMessage.Body.BodyType does anyone know the assignment vvalue for HTML for this proprety so I could just put msg.Body.BodyType = assignment value; msg.Body = body;

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.messagebody.bodytype

Comment: found it, the assignment value is HTML so msg.Body.BodyType = "HTML" works. It also seems to autoassign if you introduce the HTML first.

Answer (score 0):

This will be something like:

```
EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(exService);
//assing body 1st:
msg.Body= "string in Html format with tags and stuff";
msg.Body.BodyType = BodyType.HTML;
...
```